# How to add items in Spinner Android 3.5?

Tags: android

### not working below code for Spinner Android 3.5

```
Android studio does not show method createFromResource() for ArrayAdapter.

ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> adapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(this,
        R.array.planets_array, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
spinner.setAdapter(adapter);
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you properly imported the ArrayAdapter class in your code?

Add this line in your code:
`import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;`

Answer (score 0):

Here is a sample code that adds items to Spinner. Hope this helps.

```
package com.example.demo;

import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.text.TextUtils;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.Toast;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatSpinner;

import com.example.demo.R;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;


public class DemoActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements  AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener {

    private AppCompatSpinner spinner_demo;
    private ArrayList<String> Items = new ArrayList<String>();
    public static ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> allItems = new ArrayList<>();
    private String selectedSpinner = "";


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.demo);

        spinner_demo = (AppCompatSpinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner_demo);

        spinner_demo.setOnItemSelectedListener(this);

        setData ();

    }


    private void setData () {

                                            HashMap<String, String> row1, row2, row3;

                                                row1 = new HashMap<>();

                                                allItems.add(row1);
                                                Items.add("Select item");

                                                row2 = new HashMap<>();
                                                row2.put("Text", "This is item A");

                                                allItems.add(row2);
                                                //Add the human readable string for user here
                                                Items.add("This is item A");

                                                row3 = new HashMap<>();
                                                row3.put("Text", "This is item B");

                                                allItems.add(row3);
                                                //Add the human readable string for user here
                                                Items.add("This is item B");


                                            ArrayAdapter<String> adapter_State = new ArrayAdapter<String>(activity,
                                                    android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, Items);
                                            adapter_State
                                                    .setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
                                            spinner_demo.setAdapter(adapter_State);


    }


    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        super.onResume();

    }


    public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View params, int position,
                               long id) {

        switch(parent.getId()){

            case R.id.spinner_demo:

                spinner_demo.setSelection(position);

                String selectedSpinner = allItems.get(position).get("Text");

                break;

                default:

                    AppLog.Log("TAG", "Selected Spinner : " + parent.getId());

                    break;

        }

    }

    @Override
    public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

}
```